# Expectation of staying in same state for a simple MC

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Consider a simple dicrete-time Markov Chain $X_t$ with finite state $\Omega = \{1,2,3\}$. At time 0 the chain is with probability 1 in state 1 $\mathbb{P}(X_0 = 1) =1$. Then the transition probability matrix is as follows
\begin{array}{ccc}
p_{11} & p_{12} & 0 \\
0 & p_{22} & p_{23}\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
I would simply like to know the expectation of the time the chain stays in each state. For state 1 is it simply $\mathbb{E}(T_1) = \sum_{k > 0} k p_{11}^k$ ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $T_1 = \max\{i, X_i = 1\}$

$$P(T_1 = k) = p_{11}^{k}(1-p_{11})$$
$$E(T_1) = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}kP(T_1 = k)$$

You've forgotten the term $1-p_{11}$. Of course the result can be simplified if you want

Comment: Thx! So it is just a geometric law ?

Comment: @user3254263 yes exactly!

Comment: Last question, would it be the same for the other states ? Namely $ \mathbb{E}(T_2) = \sum_{k>0} k p_{22}^k p_{23} $

Comment: @user3254263 It's a bit different since you need to consider when is the first time that the chain arrives at the second state

Comment: Do you mean that I have to compute this probability : $ P(T_2=k) = \sum_{i>0}P(T_2=k|T_1=i)P(T_1=i)$ ?

Comment: @user3254263 yes, that's what I mean. But in fact, since the  Chain will always go to state 2, you can begin counting from the momemnt it enters state 2, thus your previous statement is true